# Why is the following Hello World program not showing any output on PowerShell ? The same program show correct output on CMD

Tags: c++, .net, powershell

Okay so here is a C++ .NET Console Hello World app.

Code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above program when debugged in Visual Studio works fine and outputs "Hello World" as expected. The same behaviour is shown when the program in executed from CMD.

But, when I execute this program from PowerShell, nothing happens ! It's as if there was no cout statement and the program just exits. Please Help

Comment: How are you running it? Is it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293279/how-do-i-run-c-program-in-powershell-just-like-cmd)?

Comment: Yup, after the compilation, I run the exe file from PowerShell using the command Hello.exe. Well following the the link you referenced, if I do execute the program from PowerShell using ./Test or .\Test instead of Test or Test.exe, the program outputs just fine. Still a doubt, why does not powershell show any output with the simple Test command?

Comment: Run it like `& ".\test.exe" arg1 arg2 arg3` if you haven't and maybe try `cmd /c "test.exe"`

Comment: Why does the other way of executing the program from powershell not work ?, i.e, why does writing Test not work but ./Test or .\Test work ?

Comment: Test.exe is reserved for binary modules imported to powershell already or part of the path environment variable I believe, when you run a script or something, you have to put the full path as it is not defined in powershell by default. `.\ ` just means current directory.

Comment: Yup thats the case. Putting the full path instead does the job. Anyways, I can change the name of the compiled binary too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run exe's in powershell mainly like

```
& ".\test.exe" arg1 arg2 arg3
```

and maybe

```
cmd /c "test.exe"
```

If you run your script just like

```
test.exe
```

Most of the time it won't work since calling like that are reserved for imported binary modules or files in the `path` environment variable. `.\` represents the current directory (i.e. `gci .\`) so to run your `exe` file, you woul either need to call the file with

```
& .\test.exe
& "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"
```

or just without the ampersand `&` and with the full path like

```
C:\Path\To\File\Without\Spaces.exe
C:\"Program Files"\Git\cmd\git.exe
.\test.exe
```

Comment: Thanks it worked ! By the way, adding to path did work too !