# Printing Hello World in c++ on Windows

Tags: c++, powershell

I used to code a little in c++ in my university days (now mostly python) and I wanted to brush off my skills, but embarrassingly I can't even seem to print a simple hello world on Windows (back in the day I only used Linux). So I wrote the code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!"<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which is pretty straightforward. I compiled using g++ on Powershell

```
g++ Test.cpp -o Hello.exe
```

Which compiles without errors (If I make a mistake it does print an error and does not compile). But when I tried to execute it nothing works. I have read of previous similar issues (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368430/why-is-the-following-hello-world-program-not-showing-any-output-on-powershell) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293279/how-do-i-run-c-program-in-powershell-just-like-cmd) for example) and I have tried to execute using `Hello.exe` `.\Hello.exe`, `Full path\Hello.exe`, `& .\Hello.exe` and various other combinations without success. Significantly I don't see any output even when using the command prompt (I also tried to recompile and execute from the command prompt but nothing) Finally I though that maybe this is happening because I work on a network drive (being this my work computer) so I copied the file on the C:\ disk and tried to execute it with the command prompt, still without success. At this point run out of ideas so I'd be happy for any suggestion.

EDIT: when I compile the file it does create an executable

EDIT 2: I tested it again on my machine which runs Windows 10 (as my university machine) works flawlessly, so it seems, as some have suggested in the comments, that there is some security mechanism that is blocking the execution on my uni machine

Comment: Confirm the executable is formed or not. Can you run the executable?

Comment: Maybe the windows defender or other software blocks the execution of Hello.exe?

Comment: Window often has an option to *detect* potential malwares by sending any unknown executable to a central server before executing  it locally. That can easily delay execution by several minutes...

Comment: It does create an executable in all cases

Comment: Try running the program from a command prompt rather than power shell.  Its possible you are missing some DLL and PS is hiding that error from you.  To start a command prompt from `PS>` type `cmd`

Comment: If you have verified that your antivirus is not the problem (it often is for cases like this), maybe you have a problem with your MinGW install. Perhaps you don't have the correct bin folder added to your `PATH` environment variable or perhaps you have more than 1 MinGW added and the first one is wrong. My advice is to remove all instances of MinGW and use msys2 to install mingw: [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/)

Comment: What does this have to do with PS? You are trying to run it from a PS terminal? I think the C++ folks can help but the PS tag should be removed.